# How to rotate Circle Menu?

Tags: css, menu, rotation

how to rotate Circle Menu by 180 degrees?

I do not know, maybe the fault of the late hour, but I have no idea what degrees to enter all turned 180 degrees :/

http://dabblet.com/gist/3979221/cb69c5e8ccf0745fff2c94b47b27b108931f1a15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.button:focus + .tip {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
    transform:rotateZ(180deg);
}
```

It i where you should set menu rotation i guess, else i misunderstood your question.
http://dabblet.com/gist/5846418

(did it help ?)
If not, then the long way :

For each buttons, you will have to add 180deg to their actual values.

For the edges, make value positive negative and vice-versa.
change top coordonates for bottom coordanates, same values.
http://dabblet.com/gist/5846462

Comment: Thanks, that was it :)

I do not know why do not I think... ;)

Comment: like you said too late and so,  maybe too obvious to mind it